# Change the sliding speed of Coda Slider 1.1.1

Tags: javascript, coda-slider

I have a wordpress template that makes use of Coda Slider 1.1.1, and although I have figured out how to make it transition less frequently, I can't figure out how to change the physical speed at which the elements slide across the screen. I'm looking at the coda-slider.1.1.1.pack.js file but can't see it in there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can adjust the slide speed with that:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('#coda-slider').codaSlider({
        autoSlide: true,
        autoSlideInterval: 4000,
    });
});
```

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Coda slider  1.1.1 pack js.. You can use this code to auto slide :

```
    jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
        jQuery("div#slider1").codaSlider({ continuous:true}) 
        jQuery("div#slider2").codaSlider()
          // etc, etc. Beware of cross-linking difficulties if using multiple sliders on one page.
var autoSlide = setInterval(function()
      {
        jQuery("#stripNavR0 a").click();
        }, 6000);
    });
```

Instead of `#stripnavR0` a use the id for the div use on right click of your slider.